# getting URL generated by breeze

Tags: jquery, breeze

I am currently using breeze at client side. I am writing a linq query and using breeze to convert it to URL query which will hit my server. I was wondering if there is any way to find out at client side  the URL it generates.

Code i am using:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Partners");
manager.executeQuery(query, function (data) {
var results = data.results;
...............................
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented *_toUri* method on the *EntityQuery* type. It takes a *MetadataStore* as its argument.

```
 var query = new EntityQuery()
        .from("Customers")
        .where("companyName", "startsWith", "C")
        .orderBy("companyName");
 var queryUrl = query._toUri(myEntityManager.metadataStore);
```

Note that this method is NOT guaranteed to continue to be available, so using it for debugging or learning OData syntax is fine, but do not depend on it in production.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to use the URL for?  Have you examined the query object at all?  It contains the resource name which is the path that is appended to your API's URL when the query is executed and is available *before* the query executes -

```
var resource = query.resourceName;
```

If you added this on to your `entityManager`'s serviceName you could create the URL Breeze will use -

```
var fullPath = manager.serviceName + query.resourceName;
```

When the query completes successfully both objects are returned as well so you could check which manager was used, it's serviceName, and the queries resourceName then as well.

Comment: The query.resourceName is only the endpoint; it does not include the OData querystring that Breeze generates which is presumably why you would want to see the generated URL.